# How to detect left and right side of face?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am using opencv sharp, and haar cascaes for profile face, but i wanna know the side of the face detected. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could determine the position of the eyes and then check, which eye is on your side. the symetric axis of the face is at the middle of the distance between your eyes.

as far as i know, opencv has some built in functionality to find eyes within the face - or at least some libraries using opencv do (i.e. emgu)

Comment: Gosh why didt i think of it .......... Thanks, but wouldnt it slow down the process, if its implemented for video?

Comment: possible - I'd test it and if it's slowed down, maybe you can skip frames (look at every 20th frame). since we - mankind - are only able to recognize 25 - 30 frames per second, you don't have to do this for every frame. therefore it should be okay.